# What happens behind the scenes when a EU COVID-19 vaccine certificate gets scanned?

Tags: covid-19, vaccinations

There is a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) which I think gets translated into an ID. How does that ID get checked? Is there a request to a common EU database with Switzerland and UK?

Comment: The UK is not in the EU, and is not part of any EU covid vaccine database initiative.

Comment: My vauge understanding is that the UK is using the same underlying system but with it's own signing key and at least some EU countries are accepting UK signed certs.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Certificate functions as follows:

1. The EU Digital COVID Certificate contains a QR code with a digital
   signature to protect it against falsification.
2. When the certificate is checked, the QR code is scanned and the
   signature verified.
3. Each issuing body (e.g. a hospital, a test centre, a health
   authority) has its own digital signature key. All of these are
   stored in a secure database in each country.
4. The European Commission has built a gateway through which all
   certificate signatures can be verified across the EU. The personal
   data of the certificate holder does not pass through the gateway, as
   this is not necessary to verify the digital signature. The European
   Commission also helped Member States to develop national software
   and apps to issue, store and verify certificates and supported them
   in the necessary tests to on-board the gateway.

[Source](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/coronavirus-response/safe-covid-19-vaccines-europeans/eu-digital-covid-certificate_en#how-will-the-certificate-work)

The specifications have all been published on [github](https://github.com/eu-digital-green-certificates)

Comment: Recommend that this is made the accepted answer.

Comment: And all I did was quote the official explanation…

Comment: The QR code contains a base45 encoded string that is zlib-compressed. When decompresed, the result is a CBOR Web Token structure. This structure contains all relevant data. The application, which is regularly updated, will check the digital signature (thus works offline). (The process is described in the gibhub link provided in this answer)

Answer (score 34):

Given that the check also works offline (just tested it myself with the CovPass Check app), there cannot be any requests to any server. However, what the QR code includes, is data about the person (name and date of birth), as well as the information if the vaccination is complete (at least for the digital certificate issued in Germany). That data is most likely signed with a private key from the issuer, and this signature can then be validated with a public key, that's part of the check app. This process doesn't require any internet connection (the process of creating the QR code requires it, since it has to be generated by the holder of the private key).

Comment: Had the same experience with another national app some time ago. It does check a server regularly, possibly to update/add/revoke public keys. I haven't investigated this further.

Comment: You are completely right. The data includes the name and date of birth of the holder, some details about the vaccine (against which disease, manufacturer, batch number etc), which "number" eg "1 of 2", "2 of 2" or "1 of 1" and the date the vaccine was given. This data is then signed by an authorized vaccine certificate issuer with a private key. The verification apps only need to have a list of the public certificates of the trusted issuers. This list can be updated infrequently with only occasional network access and the technology does not need network access for the actual verification.

Comment: I’d also note that online checks would be a massive privacy breach as they would let the government track your movements using check in data.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not if the authorities do now know who is checking your status from where. That would easy to prevent.

Comment: @JonathanReez The "massive privacy breach" is simply called a smartphone. And many people use it to save and display the mentioned QR code.

Comment: That's exactly how it works. This architecture also makes it easy for a third party to join the system: it just needs to have the public key of its health authority included in the system. The whole point of this system is to avoid having a central database with vaccination data. Once the certificate is generated, it doesn't need to be stored anywhere by the authorities, the end user is the only one with a copy.

Comment: @JonathanReez well, many governments already require everyone to leave their personal data everywhere they go (restaurants, hairdressers, etc.) in order to "track infections". So privacy has already been abolished, independently of whether the EU DCC gets checked online or offline...

Comment: So assumedly, one could print out a physical copy of the QR code and use that instead.

Comment: Yes, in fact when i got the certificate, i got a printout at the pharmacy and scanned that printed QR code with the app

Comment: @stanri actually a QR is not anything else than a fancy of way to encode information. You could have the same information printed as a number. The QR is used because it is very easy to read by computers and that it is very compact when compared with other computer-readable formats like barcodes.

Comment: @wimi But this is generally in the form of a handwritten entry on a piece of paper that will not normally be used.

Comment: @RobinSalih Actually here in Germany most places have transitioned to online registration, with the paper form only used as a fallback mode.

Comment: The CovPass Check app is open source, the certificate check is [here](https://github.com/Digitaler-Impfnachweis/covpass-android/blob/main/covpass-sdk/src/main/java/de/rki/covpass/sdk/cert/CertValidator.kt).

Comment: @SJuan yes but QR codes are often used for initiating a 2-way connection.  Eg masterpass, watsapp web interface, and the discord web login all use QR code information to initiate communication with a service. It is feasible to ask if this QR code is the same (used to initiate a connection that is afterwards continued) vs a one-way supply of information once off. Hence my paper comment.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes but QR Codes are barcodes, just in 2 dimensions.

Comment: i'm annoyed with the whole thing unfortunately - as "rant" deleted before - but "side-channel" attacks are common
--
first - it is very unfortunate that the "security" and afterwards "belief" is used to justify the introduction of public private keys in transactions between humans.

To use tech to secure websites ok, but everything beyond not so much. And yes there are revocation lists already implemented which need to be synched (the app need online access - what you get from an apple/google play store is unclear - who says they don't leak - possibly introduced in future updates)